# iOS - Swift - How to display UIAlertViewController without disabling background

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I wanted to display a Popup view on top of the screen but while enabling the actual screen as well. User should be able to perform all touch actions on the screen's controller while displaying and allowing touch actions on popup view as well. No fade for background ofcourse.

I do not see a existing style for UIAlertController that meets this need.
Is it possible with UIAlertController?
(PS. with UIPopoverPresentationController Custom style, managed to disable fade but still couldn't get the touch controls work on background screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to look into passthroughViews property on UIPopoverPresentationController. From the documentation:

"When displayed, taps outside of the popover window cause the popover to be dismissed automatically. To allow the user to interact with the specified views and not dismiss the popover, you can assign one or more views to the passthroughViews property."
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/